# Is it possible to have a ShareItem call a method when sharekit finishes sharing?

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, sharekit

When the user posts to FB or Twitter I want to know that the share completed, or the view was dismissed with an x.

Does anyone know if there is a delegate method built into ShareKit or if I have to write my own methods into it?

Right now I'm using the sharers directly, but I may switch to use the sharekit popup. I'm just using the two line code:

```
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

Comment: Having the same issue over here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced your problem and came out with a solution, perhaps not the prettiest one, but it does solve the problem. There is a delagate called SHKSharerDelegate, which can be used with sharers for this purpouse, so if you are calling sharers directly from your code (no action sheet), then you should do something like this:

```
NSString* mySharerClassName = @"SHKFacebook";
SHKSharer* classItem = (SHKSharer*)[[NSClassFromString(mySharerClassName) alloc] init];
Class sharerClass = [classItem class];

if ( [sharerClass canShare] ){
    [classItem performSelector: @selector(setItem:) withObject: item];
    //Assuming that the class where this code is conforms to the SHKSharerDelegate protocol
    [classItem performSelector: @selector(setShareDelegate:) withObject: self];
    [classItem performSelector: @selector(send)];
}
```

If you have to use the ActionSheet, it gets a little trickier, mostly because there is no support for it, just go to the ActionSheet header file (ShareKit/UI/SHKActionSheet.h) and add a delegate property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id sharerDelegate;
```

**Notice that is not `id<SHKSharerDelegate>`, try doing that and you'll experience a whole lot of pain**. That's why I said that is not the prettiest one. Once you added and synthetized the property, look for this method:

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

And where it says

```
id sharer = [sharers objectAtIndex:buttonIndex];
[NSClassFromString(sharer) performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];
```

Change it for

```
id sharer = [sharers objectAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if ( sharerDelegate == nil ){
    [NSClassFromString(sharer) performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];
}else{
    SHKSharer* classItem = [[NSClassFromString(sharer) alloc] init];
    [classItem performSelector: @selector(setItem:) withObject: item];
    [classItem performSelector: @selector(setShareDelegate:) withObject: sharerDelegate];
    [classItem performSelector: @selector(send)];
}
```

If you are more interested in this, I'll try to make a blog post soon and edit the answer to reference it.
Hope I can still help somebody!

Comment: well you sure helped me :)

Comment: FYI, the fix for the actionsheet approach is out of date with the current version ShareKit (as in, the code has changed)

Comment: Well, this question is over a year old, I would be very worried if ShareKit hadn't changed since then :)